# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus in the Form $f(x_0 + h) = f(x_0) + \int_{x_0}^{x_0 + h} f'(\tau) \ d \tau$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

My textbook has written the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus in the form

> $$f(x_0 + h) = f(x_0) + \int_{x_0}^{x_0 + h} f'(\tau) \ d \tau$$

I've never seen this form and don't understand how it comes about. I searched through the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus), but I can't seem to find anything resembling this form.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please explain this form of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and demonstrate how it comes about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same thing as this:
$$
f(b)-f(a) = \int_a^b f'(x)\;dx
$$
if you make the appropriate changes.

Comment: Oh, of course. I can't believe I missed it. Thanks for the clarification!